# How to load default Component in default App and next to do redirect to another sub app?

Tags: single-spa, single-spa-angular

I Have 3 apps : root-config (single-spa), navbar-app  ( port 4201 angular 12 ) angular-app (port 4202 angular 12 )

1. My root-config app (localhost:9000) has  `root-config.ts`

```
registerApplication({
    name: "@org1/myNavbarApp",
    app: () => System.import("@org1/myNavbarApp"),
    activeWhen: ["/"],
});

registerApplication({
    name: "@org1/myAngularApp",
    app: () => System.import("@org1/myAngularApp"),
    activeWhen: ['/angular']
});
```

2. my myNavbarApp has `app-routing.module.ts`

````
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,
  }, {
    path: 'menu',
    component: MenuComponent,
  },
  {path: '**', component: EmptyRouteComponent}, // <-- will display angular app but will not 
leave <mat-toolbar> in view from myNavBarApp ( only if i stay in localhost:4200/menu 
and do refresh -> angular app default view displays under <mat-toolbar> of 
myNavBarApp ( as expected behavior ) 

// {path: '**', redirectTo: 'login'},  // <-- renders default "login.component" on first load 
of localhost:9000 (exactly what i need) but will cause next issue: 
after navigateToUrl('angular') is done - ```login.component``` angular app content 
are visible in the same page - ( not expected behavior )

];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
  enableTracing: false,
  relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',
};


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]

})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
````

3. NavBarApp has `menu.component.html` includes next:

```
<mat-toolbar color="warn" class="toolbar">
  <mat-button-toggle-group class="menu">
    <mat-button-toggle (click)="singleSpaNavigateUrl('angular')" value="angular">Angular App</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and `menu.component.ts`  includes next :

`import {getAppNames, navigateToUrl, getMountedApps} from "single-spa";`

```
public singleSpaNavigateUrl(url: string) {
  console.log('appNames', getAppNames()); <-- IS ALWAYS EMPTY ARRAY , Why ?
  console.log('mountedAppNames', getMountedApps()); <-- IS ALWAYS EMPTY ARRAY , Why ?

  navigateToUrl('/'+ url); // <-- navigates to /angular
}
```

1. How to achieve myNavBarApp `menu.component`  will stay visible in all child apps after login / or when is needed ?
2. How to achieve `login.component` as default , when myNavBarApp is loaded from root-config app in browser ( without entering "/login" manually after that)
3. Single spa documentation says: `single-spa Layout Engine is optional at this time but is recommended if you foresee utilizing server side rendering` .. So i do not have server rendering ...thats why i do not implement layouts , and want to know how it possible to do without it ?
4. Why `getAppNames()`  and `getMountedApps()` returns always empty array ?